# How to split pandas dataframe single row into two rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to split the single row of the Dataframe into two rows. In the Dataframe start and end columns are available. I want to split the rows depends on the condition.

**I have one Dataframe like below:**

```
symbol,start,end,size
ABC,2015-08-27 18:00:00,2015-08-28 05:00:00,12
ABC,2015-11-20 02:00:00,2015-11-20 06:00:00,5
ABC,2016-01-22 03:00:00,2016-01-22 06:00:00,4
PQR,2016-02-12 02:00:00,2016-02-12 06:00:00,5
PQR,2016-02-12 22:00:00,2016-02-13 03:00:00,6
PQR,2016-02-12 02:00:00,2016-02-12 07:00:00,6
```

**Condition:**

1. If the start and end is same day then no need to perform anything.
2. If the start and end is different day then need to split it into two rows.

Example: let's consider row like:

```
PQR,2016-02-12 22:00:00,2016-02-13 03:00:00,6
```

In the above row, start contains day as 12th and end contains day as 13th so, need to split it into two rows like below:

```
PQR,2016-02-12 22:00:00,2016-02-12 23:00:00,2
PQR,2016-02-12 00:00:00,2016-02-13 03:00:00,4
```

If the row contains three days like in start 12th and in end 14th then need to split it into three rows.

**Expected output would be:**

```
symbol,start,end,size
ABC,2015-08-27 18:00:00,2015-08-27 23:00:00,6
ABC,2015-08-28 00:00:00,2015-08-28 05:00:00,6
ABC,2015-11-20 02:00:00,2015-11-20 06:00:00,5
ABC,2016-01-22 03:00:00,2016-01-22 06:00:00,4
PQR,2016-02-12 02:00:00,2016-02-12 06:00:00,5
PQR,2016-02-12 22:00:00,2016-02-12 23:00:00,2
PQR,2016-02-12 00:00:00,2016-02-13 03:00:00,4
PQR,2016-02-12 02:00:00,2016-02-12 07:00:00,6
```

Comment: where does the '23:00:00' in the first line of your third code block come from? I don't see it in the original data. Same goes for the '00:00:00' in the second line of the same code block. Did you forget to name another condition ?

Comment: @sudonym- It is hours. In one day hours ends with 23 and starts with 00 and need to split this data day wise.

Comment: I got that, However, the hour '23:00:00' is not present in your input data. Same goes for '00:00:00'. This means you must have a rule to determine this hour. This rule is not present in your code. Therefore (again) the question: How to know those hours for the other rows?

Comment: @sudonym my guess is that you have to imagine starting times as they are (00:00) and ending times as if they had minutes and seconds set to 59:59

Comment: in the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess :)

Comment: @sudonym- I mean, one guesses, sees that with the guess the univers (or a tiny part of it, a stackoverflow question) makes more sense, and then goes on with that... :) In any case, the real question would be, if you only care about hour precision (as I guess -sorry- it is the case here) is there a way (a simple way) to remove minutes and seconds from the datetime column? at least for display purposes. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Iterate over rows and build a new `DataFrame` appending row by row.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

for (_,r) in df.iterrows():

    while r['start'].date()<r['end'].date():
        # create new row
        newR = r.copy()
        newR['end']=newR['start']
        newR['end']=newR['end'].replace(hour=23)

        newSize = 24-newR['start'].hour
        newR['size']=newSize

        # update row to process 
        r['start']=r['start']+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        r['start']=r['start'].replace(hour=0)

        r['size'] = r['size'] - newSize

        df2 = df2.append(newR)

    df2 = df2.append(r)

df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

**Option 2**

Do the operation `Dataframe`-wise using a mask, with a recursive call, in case there were rows in the original `Dataframe` to be splitted in more than two days.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime


def splitMultiDayRows(df):
    mask = df['end'].dt.day>df['start'].dt.day

    if np.any(mask):
        df_new = df.loc[mask]

        newSizes = 24-df.loc[mask,'start'].dt.hour

        df.loc[mask,'end'] = df.loc[mask,'start']
        df.loc[mask,'end'] = df.loc[mask,
                                    'end'].apply(lambda x:
                                                 x.replace(hour=23))
        df.loc[mask,'size'] = newSizes

        df_new.loc[:,'start'] = df_new['start']+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        df_new.loc[:,'start'] = df_new['start'].apply(lambda x:
                                                      x.replace(hour=0))

        df_new.loc[:,'size'] = df_new['size'] - newSizes

        return pd.concat([df,splitMultiDayRows(df_new)])
    else:
        return df
```

Use with call:

```
splitMultiDayRows(df.copy()).\
sort_values(['symbol','start']).\
reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: @Herrlvan- Iterating the DataFrame which makes tool very time consuming. You have idea to accomplish this without iterating DataFrame?

Comment: @kit- Option 2 does not iterate by row now

Answer (score 1):

This answer avoids to iterate over and does not copy unnecessary rows, therefore you will save time and space.

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

mask_to_change = df.apply(lambda x: x['end'].day > x['start'].day, axis=1)

for (_,r) in df[mask_to_change].iterrows():

    while r['start'].date()<r['end'].date():
        # create new row
        newR = r.copy()
        newR['end']=newR['start']
        newR['end']=newR['end'].replace(hour=23)

        newSize = 24-newR['start'].hour
        newR['size']=newSize

        # update row to process 
        r['start']=r['start']+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        r['start']=r['start'].replace(hour=0)

        r['size'] = r['size'] - newSize

        df2 = df2.append(newR)

    df2 = df2.append(r)

df = pd.concat([df[~mask_to_change], df2])
df.sort_values(['symbol', 'start'], inplace=True)
```