# How to split pandas Dataframe single row into two or more rows based on month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a Dataframe of a vehicle for which I have vehicle starting time and finishing time, it looks like the following Dataframe

```
    Vehicle          Start                      Finish              Time
    abc123  2021-07-05 12:17:59.567999  2021-07-06 09:17:59.496001  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-06 09:17:59.532000  2021-07-07 06:17:59.460000  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-07 06:17:59.496001  2021-07-07 11:17:59.423999  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-07 11:17:59.460001  2021-07-08 08:17:59.388000  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-08 08:17:59.423999  2021-07-08 13:17:59.352000  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-08 13:17:59.387999  2021-07-09 10:17:59.316000  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-09 10:17:59.352000  2021-07-10 07:17:59.280000  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-10 07:17:59.316000  2021-07-10 12:17:59.244000  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-12 06:00:00.035999  2021-08-10 08:47:23.963999  202.79
    abc123  2021-08-16 08:47:23.928000  2021-08-17 09:32:23.856000  8.75
    abc123  2021-08-14 06:47:23.964000  2021-08-16 08:47:23.892000  10.0
```

From this Dataframe, I want to create the following Dataframe (or expected output)

```
    Vehicle          Start                      Finish              Time
    abc123  2021-07-05 12:17:59.567999  2021-07-06 09:17:59.496001  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-06 09:17:59.532000  2021-07-07 06:17:59.460000  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-07 06:17:59.496001  2021-07-07 11:17:59.423999  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-07 11:17:59.460001  2021-07-08 08:17:59.388000  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-08 08:17:59.423999  2021-07-08 13:17:59.352000  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-08 13:17:59.387999  2021-07-09 10:17:59.316000  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-09 10:17:59.352000  2021-07-10 07:17:59.280000  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-10 07:17:59.316000  2021-07-10 12:17:59.244000  5.0
    abc123  2021-07-12 06:00:00.035999  2021-07-31 00:00:23.963999  139
    abc123  2021-08-1 06:00:00          2021-08-10 08:47:23.963999  63
    abc123  2021-08-16 08:47:23.928000  2021-08-17 09:32:23.856000  8.75
    abc123  2021-08-14 06:47:23.964000  2021-08-16 08:47:23.892000  10.0
```

Time calculation is based on approximate proportion of *202.79* based on number of days. It may be possible that some vehicle is used for consecutive three months, then I want to create **three** rows, finishing date will be *30/31* based on month. I have tried the following code based on

[How to split pandas dataframe single row into two rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962722/how-to-split-pandas-dataframe-single-row-into-two-rows)

**Source code of df:**

```
data =  [['abc123', '2021-07-05 12:17:59.567999',   '2021-07-06 09:17:59.496001', 5.0],
    ['abc123',  '2021-07-06 09:17:59.532000',   '2021-07-07 06:17:59.460000',   5.0],
    ['abc123',  '2021-07-07 06:17:59.496001',   '2021-07-07 11:17:59.423999',   5.0],
    ['abc123',  '2021-07-07 11:17:59.460001',   '2021-07-08 08:17:59.388000',   5.0],
    ['abc123',  '2021-07-08 08:17:59.423999',   '2021-07-08 13:17:59.352000',   5.0],
    ['abc123',  '2021-07-08 13:17:59.387999',   '2021-07-09 10:17:59.316000',   5.0],
    ['abc123',  '2021-07-09 10:17:59.352000',   '2021-07-10 07:17:59.280000',   5.0],
    ['abc123',  '2021-07-10 07:17:59.316000',   '2021-07-10 12:17:59.244000',   5.0],
    ['abc123',  '2021-07-12 06:00:00.035999',   '2021-08-10 08:47:23.963999',   202.79],
    ['abc123',  '2021-08-16 08:47:23.928000',   '2021-08-17 09:32:23.856000',   8.75],
    ['abc123',  '2021-08-14 06:47:23.964000',   '2021-08-16 08:47:23.892000',   10.0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Vehicle', 'Start', 'Finish', 'Time']) \
       .astype({'Start': 'datetime64', 'Finish': 'datetime64'})
```

I did this, the code is,

```
def splitMultiDayRows(df):
    mask = df['Finish'].dt.month > df['Start'].dt.month

    if np.any(mask):
        df_new = df.loc[mask]
        df_new['last_date'] = df_new['Start'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
        df_new['inter_time'] = df_new['Finish'] - df_new['Start']
        df_new['inter_time1'] = df_new['last_date'] - df_new['Start'] 
        df_new['inter_time2'] = df_new['Finish'] - df_new['last_date']
        df_new['new_date'] = df_new['last_date'] + dt.timedelta(days=1)
        #df_new.drop(['last_date'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
        df1 = df_new[['Vehicle', 'Start', 'last_date', 'Time', 'inter_time1', 'inter_time']]
        df2 = df_new[['Vehicle', 'new_date', 'Finish', 'Time', 'inter_time2', 'inter_time']]
        df2.columns = ['Vehicle', 'Start', 'last_date', 'Time', 'inter_time1', 'inter_time']
        df_Temp = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 0)
        df_Temp['Time'] = (df_Temp['inter_time1']/ df_Temp['inter_time']) * df_Temp['Time']
        df_Temp.drop(['inter_time1', 'inter_time'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
        df_Temp.columns = ['Vehicle', 'Start', 'Finish', 'Time']
        return pd.concat([df,splitMultiDayRows(df_Temp)])
    else:
        return df
    
df4 = splitMultiDayRows(df).sort_values(['Start']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The output is,

```
    Vehicle         Start                        Finish             Time
0   abc123  2021-07-05 12:17:59.567999  2021-07-06 09:17:59.496001  5.0
1   abc123  2021-07-06 09:17:59.532000  2021-07-07 06:17:59.460000  5.0
2   abc123  2021-07-07 06:17:59.496001  2021-07-07 11:17:59.423999  5.0
3   abc123  2021-07-07 11:17:59.460001  2021-07-08 08:17:59.388000  5.0
4   abc123  2021-07-08 08:17:59.423999  2021-07-08 13:17:59.352000  5.0
5   abc123  2021-07-08 13:17:59.387999  2021-07-09 10:17:59.316000  5.0
6   abc123  2021-07-09 10:17:59.352000  2021-07-10 07:17:59.280000  5.0
7   abc123  2021-07-10 07:17:59.316000  2021-07-10 12:17:59.244000  5.0
9   abc123  2021-07-12 06:00:00.035999  2021-07-31 06:00:00.035999  132.33194900705357
10  abc123  2021-08-01 06:00:00.035999  2021-08-10 08:47:23.963999  70.4580509929464
11  abc123  2021-08-14 06:47:23.964000  2021-08-16 08:47:23.892000  10.0
12  abc123  2021-08-16 08:47:23.928000  2021-08-17 09:32:23.856000  8.75
```

**Is there any alternative way to solve it?**

Comment: I don't understand why (for 139) `2021-07-12 06:00:00.035999` -> `2021-07-31 00:00:23.963999` and not `2021-07-12 06:00:00.035999` -> `2021-07-31 23:59:59.999999`? Same (for 63) `2021-08-1 06:00:00` ->  `2021-08-10 08:47:23.963999` instead of `2021-08-01 00:00:00.000000` -> `2021-08-10 08:47:23.963999`. Where is the time between `2021-07-31 00:00:23.963999` and `2021-08-1 06:00:00` (1 days 05:59:36.036001)?

Comment: @Corralien Sir basically I want to split the rows if rows starting time and finishing time is not in the same month. For 202.79, the finishing time month is 8 and and starting time month is 7, that is why I have taken ```df['Finish'].dt.month > df['Start'].dt.month```. One can take any time between ```2021-07-31 00:00:23.963999 and 2021-08-1 06:00:00```. As I am trying to split it approximately, if one can write ```2021-07-31 00:00:00 (finishing time for splitting) and 2021-08-1 06:00:00 (starting time)```

Answer (score 1):

From your last dataframe, you want to drop index 8. You can do like that:

```
df4 = df4.loc[df4['Start'].dt.month == df4['Finish'].dt.month]
```

```
>>> df4
   Vehicle                      Start                     Finish        Time
0   abc123 2021-07-05 12:17:59.567999 2021-07-06 09:17:59.496001    5.000000
1   abc123 2021-07-06 09:17:59.532000 2021-07-07 06:17:59.460000    5.000000
2   abc123 2021-07-07 06:17:59.496001 2021-07-07 11:17:59.423999    5.000000
3   abc123 2021-07-07 11:17:59.460001 2021-07-08 08:17:59.388000    5.000000
4   abc123 2021-07-08 08:17:59.423999 2021-07-08 13:17:59.352000    5.000000
5   abc123 2021-07-08 13:17:59.387999 2021-07-09 10:17:59.316000    5.000000
6   abc123 2021-07-09 10:17:59.352000 2021-07-10 07:17:59.280000    5.000000
7   abc123 2021-07-10 07:17:59.316000 2021-07-10 12:17:59.244000    5.000000
9   abc123 2021-07-12 06:00:00.035999 2021-07-31 06:00:00.035999  132.331949
10  abc123 2021-08-01 06:00:00.035999 2021-08-10 08:47:23.963999   70.458051
11  abc123 2021-08-14 06:47:23.964000 2021-08-16 08:47:23.892000   10.000000
12  abc123 2021-08-16 08:47:23.928000 2021-08-17 09:32:23.856000    8.750000
```

Comment: Is there any alternative way to do the problem? Thanks for your suggestion, I also did it.